# How do I add new elements to a dropdown menu using ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I would like to know how to add new elements to a dropdown menu without refreshing the html page. For example, if I have the drop down menu below:

```
<select>
<option>existing item 1<option>
<option>existing item 2<option>
<option>existing item 3<option>
<option>add new item<option>
</select>
```

Any time the user selects "add new item", a text box would pop-up asking the user for input. Then whatever string the user types in the text box, I want that to be saved to the drop down menu without refreshing the page. Of course, the "add new item" option will remain unchanged, so the user can repeat this process as many times as he/she wants.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery..

```
$("select").append("<option>Another option</option>")
```

Answer (score 0):

A non JQuery way is to use the standard JavaScript dom api like so:

This piece uses a prompt as a text popout input. If you want to make it pretty you will have to consider an UI framework.

### JavaScript :

```
var select  = document.getElementById('select');
var addNewOption = document.getElementById('addNew');
select.onclick= function(){
  if (select.value === 'addNew'){
    var text = prompt('New Value');
    if (text){
       var label =  text;
  var value = text;
  var newOption = document.createElement('option');
  newOption.innerHTML = label;
  newOption.value = value;

  select.insertBefore(newOption, addNewOption);
  select.value = value;
    }

  }
};
```

Demo here:

http://jsbin.com/sufug/2/edit

Comment: Oh I jumped to respond quick without reading the whole question... let me readjust my answer.

Comment: Take a look now, does it fit your needs ?

Comment: awesome man, that's exactly what I wanted. I can't thank you enough!